# Gulp SASS compile error - breakpoints cannot import

Tags: node.js, sass, gulp, drupal-7

I've been trying to solve Gulp errors. I am running a

- Mac OS Sierra 10.12.5
- Installed Drupal 7 locally using Acquia Dev Desktop
- I have used the Readme.txt in the Zen starter theme and I have followed the instructions in the Zen starter theme to install npm and gulpfile.js

I have gulp finding the gulpfile.js so that it will start compiling the SASS But I am encountering the following error and I can't figure out what I'm missing!

```
[iMac:foo_theme Candace$ gulp
[13:48:46] Using gulpfile ~/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/gulpfile.js
[13:48:46] Starting 'clean:css'...
[13:48:46] Starting 'clean:styleguide'...
[13:48:46] Starting 'styleguide:kss-example-chroma'...
[13:48:46] 'styleguide:kss-example-chroma' errored after 7.94 ms
[13:48:46] TypeError: $.replace is not a function
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (/Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/gulpfile.js:154:13)
    at module.exports (/Users/Candace/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (/Users/Candace/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (/Users/Candace/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:214:10)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (/Users/Candace/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:134:8)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp-cli/lib/versioned/^3.7.0/index.js:51:20
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:95:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:161:9)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:607:11)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:575:3
[13:48:46] Finished 'clean:css' after 36 ms
[13:48:46] Finished 'clean:styleguide' after 32 ms
Error: Could not import `breakpoint` from any of the following locations:
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/breakpoint.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/breakpoint.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/_breakpoint.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/_breakpoint.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/breakpoint.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/breakpoint.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/_breakpoint.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/_breakpoint.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/style-guide/breakpoint.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/style-guide/breakpoint.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/style-guide/_breakpoint.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/style-guide/_breakpoint.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/breakpoint.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/breakpoint.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/_breakpoint.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/_breakpoint.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/breakpoint-sass/stylesheets/breakpoint.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/breakpoint-sass/stylesheets/breakpoint.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/breakpoint-sass/stylesheets/_breakpoint.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/breakpoint-sass/stylesheets/_breakpoint.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/chroma-sass/sass/breakpoint.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/chroma-sass/sass/breakpoint.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/chroma-sass/sass/_breakpoint.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/chroma-sass/sass/_breakpoint.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/support-for/sass/breakpoint.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/support-for/sass/breakpoint.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/support-for/sass/_breakpoint.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/support-for/sass/_breakpoint.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/typey/stylesheets/breakpoint.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/typey/stylesheets/breakpoint.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/typey/stylesheets/_breakpoint.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/typey/stylesheets/_breakpoint.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/zen-grids/sass/breakpoint.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/zen-grids/sass/breakpoint.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/zen-grids/sass/_breakpoint.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/zen-grids/sass/_breakpoint.sass
Error: Could not import `chroma/functions` from any of the following locations:
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/chroma/functions.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/chroma/functions.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/chroma/_functions.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/chroma/_functions.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/chroma/functions.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/chroma/functions.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/chroma/_functions.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/chroma/_functions.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/style-guide/chroma/functions.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/style-guide/chroma/functions.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/style-guide/chroma/_functions.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/style-guide/chroma/_functions.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/chroma/functions.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/chroma/functions.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/chroma/_functions.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/chroma/_functions.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/breakpoint-sass/stylesheets/chroma/functions.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/breakpoint-sass/stylesheets/chroma/functions.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/breakpoint-sass/stylesheets/chroma/_functions.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/breakpoint-sass/stylesheets/chroma/_functions.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/chroma-sass/sass/chroma/functions.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/chroma-sass/sass/chroma/functions.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/chroma-sass/sass/chroma/_functions.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/chroma-sass/sass/chroma/_functions.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/support-for/sass/chroma/functions.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/support-for/sass/chroma/functions.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/support-for/sass/chroma/_functions.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/support-for/sass/chroma/_functions.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/typey/stylesheets/chroma/functions.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/typey/stylesheets/chroma/functions.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/typey/stylesheets/chroma/_functions.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/typey/stylesheets/chroma/_functions.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/zen-grids/sass/chroma/functions.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/zen-grids/sass/chroma/functions.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/zen-grids/sass/chroma/_functions.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/zen-grids/sass/chroma/_functions.sass
Error: Could not import `chroma` from any of the following locations:
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/chroma.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/chroma.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/_chroma.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/_chroma.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/chroma.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/chroma.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/_chroma.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/_chroma.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/style-guide/chroma.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/style-guide/chroma.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/style-guide/_chroma.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/style-guide/_chroma.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/chroma.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/chroma.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/_chroma.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/_chroma.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/breakpoint-sass/stylesheets/chroma.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/breakpoint-sass/stylesheets/chroma.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/breakpoint-sass/stylesheets/_chroma.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/breakpoint-sass/stylesheets/_chroma.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/chroma-sass/sass/chroma.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/chroma-sass/sass/chroma.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/chroma-sass/sass/_chroma.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/chroma-sass/sass/_chroma.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/support-for/sass/chroma.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/support-for/sass/chroma.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/support-for/sass/_chroma.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/support-for/sass/_chroma.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/typey/stylesheets/chroma.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/typey/stylesheets/chroma.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/typey/stylesheets/_chroma.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/typey/stylesheets/_chroma.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/zen-grids/sass/chroma.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/zen-grids/sass/chroma.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/zen-grids/sass/_chroma.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/zen-grids/sass/_chroma.sass
Error: Could not import `chroma/kss` from any of the following locations:
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/chroma/kss.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/chroma/kss.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/chroma/_kss.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/chroma/_kss.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/chroma/kss.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/chroma/kss.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/chroma/_kss.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/chroma/_kss.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/style-guide/chroma/kss.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/style-guide/chroma/kss.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/style-guide/chroma/_kss.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/style-guide/chroma/_kss.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/chroma/kss.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/chroma/kss.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/chroma/_kss.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/chroma/_kss.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/breakpoint-sass/stylesheets/chroma/kss.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/breakpoint-sass/stylesheets/chroma/kss.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/breakpoint-sass/stylesheets/chroma/_kss.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/breakpoint-sass/stylesheets/chroma/_kss.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/chroma-sass/sass/chroma/kss.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/chroma-sass/sass/chroma/kss.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/chroma-sass/sass/chroma/_kss.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/chroma-sass/sass/chroma/_kss.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/support-for/sass/chroma/kss.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/support-for/sass/chroma/kss.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/support-for/sass/chroma/_kss.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/support-for/sass/chroma/_kss.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/typey/stylesheets/chroma/kss.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/typey/stylesheets/chroma/kss.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/typey/stylesheets/chroma/_kss.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/typey/stylesheets/chroma/_kss.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/zen-grids/sass/chroma/kss.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/zen-grids/sass/chroma/kss.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/zen-grids/sass/chroma/_kss.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/zen-grids/sass/chroma/_kss.sass
Error: Could not import `support-for` from any of the following locations:
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/support-for.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/support-for.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/_support-for.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/_support-for.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/support-for.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/support-for.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/_support-for.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/_support-for.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/style-guide/support-for.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/style-guide/support-for.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/style-guide/_support-for.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/style-guide/_support-for.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/support-for.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/support-for.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/_support-for.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/_support-for.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/breakpoint-sass/stylesheets/support-for.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/breakpoint-sass/stylesheets/support-for.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/breakpoint-sass/stylesheets/_support-for.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/breakpoint-sass/stylesheets/_support-for.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/chroma-sass/sass/support-for.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/chroma-sass/sass/support-for.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/chroma-sass/sass/_support-for.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/chroma-sass/sass/_support-for.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/support-for/sass/support-for.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/support-for/sass/support-for.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/support-for/sass/_support-for.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/support-for/sass/_support-for.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/typey/stylesheets/support-for.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/typey/stylesheets/support-for.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/typey/stylesheets/_support-for.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/typey/stylesheets/_support-for.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/zen-grids/sass/support-for.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/zen-grids/sass/support-for.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/zen-grids/sass/_support-for.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/zen-grids/sass/_support-for.sass
Error: Could not import `typey` from any of the following locations:
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/typey.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/typey.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/_typey.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/_typey.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/typey.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/typey.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/_typey.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/_typey.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/style-guide/typey.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/style-guide/typey.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/style-guide/_typey.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/style-guide/_typey.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/typey.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/typey.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/_typey.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/_typey.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/breakpoint-sass/stylesheets/typey.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/breakpoint-sass/stylesheets/typey.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/breakpoint-sass/stylesheets/_typey.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/breakpoint-sass/stylesheets/_typey.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/chroma-sass/sass/typey.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/chroma-sass/sass/typey.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/chroma-sass/sass/_typey.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/chroma-sass/sass/_typey.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/support-for/sass/typey.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/support-for/sass/typey.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/support-for/sass/_typey.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/support-for/sass/_typey.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/typey/stylesheets/typey.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/typey/stylesheets/typey.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/typey/stylesheets/_typey.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/typey/stylesheets/_typey.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/zen-grids/sass/typey.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/zen-grids/sass/typey.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/zen-grids/sass/_typey.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/zen-grids/sass/_typey.sass
Error: Could not import `zen-grids` from any of the following locations:
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/zen-grids.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/zen-grids.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/_zen-grids.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/_zen-grids.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/zen-grids.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/zen-grids.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/_zen-grids.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/_zen-grids.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/style-guide/zen-grids.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/style-guide/zen-grids.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/style-guide/_zen-grids.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/style-guide/_zen-grids.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/zen-grids.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/zen-grids.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/_zen-grids.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/sites/all/themes/foo/sass/_zen-grids.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/breakpoint-sass/stylesheets/zen-grids.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/breakpoint-sass/stylesheets/zen-grids.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/breakpoint-sass/stylesheets/_zen-grids.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/breakpoint-sass/stylesheets/_zen-grids.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/chroma-sass/sass/zen-grids.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/chroma-sass/sass/zen-grids.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/chroma-sass/sass/_zen-grids.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/chroma-sass/sass/_zen-grids.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/support-for/sass/zen-grids.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/support-for/sass/zen-grids.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/support-for/sass/_zen-grids.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/support-for/sass/_zen-grids.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/typey/stylesheets/zen-grids.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/typey/stylesheets/zen-grids.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/typey/stylesheets/_zen-grids.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/typey/stylesheets/_zen-grids.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/zen-grids/sass/zen-grids.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/zen-grids/sass/zen-grids.sass
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/zen-grids/sass/_zen-grids.scss
  /Users/Candace/Sites/devdesktop/foo_theme/node_modules/zen-grids/sass/_zen-grids.sass
Error in plugin 'sass'
Message:
    sites/all/themes/foo/sass/init/_variables.scss
Error: no mixin named add-breakpoint

       Backtrace:
        sites/all/themes/foo/sass/init/_variables.scss:122
        on line 122 of sites/all/themes/foo/sass/init/_variables.scss
>> @include add-breakpoint(xxxs, (333px, 'no-query' true));
   ---------^
```

---

Here is the _variable.scss file:

---

```
$support-for: (
  ie:  9,
  '*': -4,
);

$base-font-size:    16px;

$base-line-height:  24px;

$font-size: (
  xxl:              32px,
  xl:               24px,
  l:                20px,
  m:                $base-font-size,
  s:                14px,
  xs:               10px
);

$font-weight: (
  bold:             bold,
  medium:           500,
  normal:           normal,
  light:            300,
  lighter:          lighter,
);

$times-new-roman: 'Times New Roman', Times, Georgia, 'DejaVu Serif', serif;
$times:           Times, 'Times New Roman', Georgia, 'DejaVu Serif', serif;
$georgia:         Georgia, 'Times New Roman', 'DejaVu Serif', serif;

$verdana:         Verdana, Tahoma, 'DejaVu Sans', sans-serif;
$tahoma:          Tahoma, Verdana, 'DejaVu Sans', sans-serif;
$helvetica:       Helvetica, Arial, 'Nimbus Sans L', sans-serif;
$arial:           Arial, Helvetica, 'Nimbus Sans L', sans-serif;
$impact:          Impact, 'Arial Narrow', Helvetica, sans-serif;

$menlo:           Menlo, 'DejaVu Sans Mono', 'Ubuntu Mono', Courier, 'Courier New', monospace, sans-serif;

$typefaces: (
  body: (
    font-family: $verdana,
  ),
  monospace: (
    font-family: $menlo,
  ),
  compact: (
    font-family: $impact,
    weight: bold,
    case: uppercase,
  ),
);

$typey-debug: false;

$base-unit:         'rem';

$rem-fallback:      false;


// Breakpoints
//
// Use the `respond-to()` mixin to use named breakpoints. Documentation is
// available in the [Breakpoint wiki
// pages](https://github.com/at-import/breakpoint/wiki/Respond-To).
//
// Style guide: sass.variables.breakpoints

@include add-breakpoint(xxxs, (333px, 'no-query' true));
@include add-breakpoint(xxs,  (444px, 'no-query' true));
@include add-breakpoint(xs,   (555px, 'no-query' true));
@include add-breakpoint(s,    (666px, 'no-query' true));
@include add-breakpoint(m,    (777px, 'no-query' true));
@include add-breakpoint(l,    (888px, 'no-query' true));
@include add-breakpoint(xl,   (999px, 'no-query' true));
@include add-breakpoint(xxl,  (1111px));
@include add-breakpoint(xxxl, (1222px));


$zen-auto-include-grid-item-base: false;
$zen-box-sizing: universal-border-box;

$zen-columns: 1;
$zen-gutters: 40px;

$zen-layouts: (
  m: (
    columns: 2,
    // The gutters in the layouts are larger on mobile.
    gutters: 25px,
  ),
  xl: (
    columns: 3,
    gutters: 25px,
  ),
);

$zen-rtl-selector: '[dir="rtl"]';

$indent-amount: 2 * $base-font-size;

$include-rtl: true;
// Automatically turn off Zen Grids' RTL support if $include-rtl is false.
@if not $include-rtl {
  $zen-rtl-selector: false !global;
}
```

I don't know what to do from here.

Comment: In `_variables.scss` you call mixin `add-breakpoint` that is not imported. Don't call it inside `_variables.scss` file.

We don't see any code. How can we help you?

Comment: Sorry, I've added in the _variable.scss code.  I'm very new to SASS and SCSS so I'm not sure exactly what is being asked for.

Comment: You are @importing breakpoint mixins without exporting them from some other file. You should do `@export 'mixins-file.scss'` and then use mixins via `@import mixin-name();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days I finally found the answer! When running gulp using Drupal 7, Zen theme - the zen theme already has gulp.js files installed.
So (if you're using mac) point your terminal to your zen sub-theme folder
cd /Users/foo_username/Sites/devdesktop/foo_subtheme/sites/all/themes/foo_themename/
Then in terminal run **npm install** and this will install all the modules needed from the package.json file found in your sub-theme folder.
Make sure you read the "readme" so that you make any changes to your gulp.js that may be required for running it on your local machine
Now you can run **gulp** and **gulp watch** without horrendous errors!